# Results in mathematics whose only proof is model theoretic

Tags: logic, model-theory, big-list

What are results in mathematics, for example in algebra, whose only proof so far used model theoretical arguments?

Comment: There is a result that I know has only model theoretic + set theoretic proof: "An Abelian group is free if and only if it has a discrete norm". I think that you can find a rich vein of similar results if you look at things provable using Shelah's "blackbox" principles.

Comment: Hrushovski's proof of the Mordell-Lang conjecture for function fields relies on model theory. As far as I know, there is no proof without model theory so far. Another example may be the Ax-Kochen-Theorem, but here I am not sure whether there are alternative proofs.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know whether or not there is a non-model theory proof, but the first proof of the "unconditional" [André-Oort conjecture for arbitrary products of modular curves](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/pila/OminimalAO.pdf)  was done by Pila using model theory (more explicitly, O-minimality).

Furthermore, there is a trend of results coming out right now linking model theory of graphs and combinatorics. For instance, see [Regularity lemmas for stable graphs](http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.3904). Since much of this work is current and still on going, I would venture to say that this result (or results like this one) only have proofs in model theory (as of now).